# is there a function call that can be used to clean up run artifacts in Jfrog pipelines

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I am using the utility function `add_run_files` and want to remove them after the run completes. How do I do this

I have gone through [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipelines+Utility+Functions#PipelinesUtilityFunctions-add_run_files) documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set retention policy in your yml like:

```
pipelines:
  - name: sample_pipeline_retention_policy
    configuration:
      retentionPolicy:
        maxAgeDays: 10
        minRuns: 5
```

All the data associated with runs exceeding the maxAgeDays will be deleted, including any storage in artifactory. Refer to [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Setting+Retention+Policy)  doc for more info